# Documentation needed for setting requirements on Android hardware supplier

Tags: android, tablet, camera

I need to put requirements for future Android hardware (tablets, phones) and I wonder if there are any guidelines or documentation of these requirements that makes it easier to follow the needed standard and get good products to use AR on?